# how to requests.get() a variable within a variable

Tags: python, python-3.x, variables, f-string

I'm using Python 3.8

I have a variable `api_url` that represents an API URL I extracted from a database. The URL can change depending on how I query the database.

```
api_url = https://system.company.com/API?%40asset={asset}
```

I now want to make an API get request using the `api_url` which contains an `{asset}` variable.

```
import requests

asset = "BuildingA"

requests.get(f"{api_url}", headers=headers)
```

But I'm pretty sure it's not working because the API call is returning a blank response. I'm assuming that the f string is not seeing `{asset}` as a variable.

Hence, my question is how do I use a variable `{asset}` within a variable `{api_url}` in a requests.get() function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot chain f-strings.

So either:

```
api_url = 'https://system.company.com/API'
requests.get(f"{api_url}?asset={asset}")
```

or

```
api_url = 'https://system.company.com/API'
requests.get(api_url, params={'asset': asset})
```

If you really want to have a predefined string that has variables, you can use format:

```
asset_url = 'https://system.company.com/API?asset={asset}'
requests.get(asset_url.format(asset=asset))
```

Comment: ＋1 for using params.  that's what it's for

Answer (score 0):

I think if api_url is `f-string` this might recognize `asset` as a variable.

```
asset = 'BuildingA'
api_url = f'https://system.company.com/API?%40asset={asset}'
```